# Adding animation to jQuery Smooth Scrolling to anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to improve the anchor scroll code I found as another question's answer. It works great for another page scrolls but scrolls without animation if it's in the same page. The thing is, I would like to have the animation for same page anchors too but I could not figure out how to include it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
    if (urlHash &&  $('#' + urlHash).length )
          $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: $('#' + urlHash).offset().top - 60
          }, 2500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you break the code out into its own function, you can then use that function in a click handler to scroll when an anchor link is clicked in addition to using it as the ready handler:

```js
function scrollToAnchor (url) {
  var urlHash = url.split('#')[1];
  if (urlHash &&  $('#' + urlHash).length) {
        $('html').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#' + urlHash).offset().top - 60
        }, 2500);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  scrollToAnchor(window.location.href);
});

$('.nav-link').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // stop the browser from snapping to the anchor
  scrollToAnchor(event.target.href);
});
```

```css
.section {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.nav {
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  position: sticky;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5em;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav">
<a class="nav-link" href="#a">A</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="#b">B</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="#c">C</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="#d">D</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="#e">E</a>
</div>

<br>
<div class="section" id="a">A</div>
<div class="section" id="b">B</div>
<div class="section" id="c">C</div>
<div class="section" id="d">D</div>
<div class="section" id="e">E</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out W3Schools?

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section1

Back when I used smooth scroll for things this code always worked for me

Comment: Hi Tom - my client's website has anchor links setup as `www.aaa.com#anchor_1` or `#anchor_2`. W3 schools code would not work with url included anchor link, I'm trying to have a combined solution.